# Date Time formatting in Workday Studio with AM/PM

Tags: workday-api

I want to format the system date time as below -

01_10_2020 08_00 AM (**MM_dd_yyyy HH_mm AM/PM**)

Currently I'm using the below code, but its throwing error - "error caused by: java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2020-10-23T20:43:17Z"

```
props['currentDateTime'] = util.currentDateTimeAsString()

props['p.parsed.date'] = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm").parse(props['currentDateTime'])
props['FormattedDate'] = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy HH_mm").format(props['p.parsed.date'])

props['p.filename'] = props['StuName']+' '+props['FormattedDate']
```

Has anyone used this date with time formatting (including AM/PM)?

Thanks,

Arnab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of this

```
    props['currentDateTime']
```

is

```
    "2020-10-23T20:43:17Z"
```

Try changing your SimpleDateFormat to match

```
    Date j = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").parse("2020-10-23T20:43:17Z");     
    String k = new SimpleDateFormat("MM_dd_yyyy HH_mm").format(j);
    System.out.println(k);
```

Comment: "MM_dd_yyyy HH_mm aa" will also add the AM/PM"